# SQL - year to date

Tags: sql

Sample data:

```
sDate         NAME   
2010-03-28    Andrew  
2011-05-10    Drew           
2010-04-11    Clary 
2009-12-26    Kriz
```

I want to sort it out so that the output will only show those that arefrom 01/01/11 to the year to date. Is there an automatic syntax so that I will not change my sql statement to the date today but it will always show the year to date?

```
Example of my statement:
SELECT *
FROM 'mytable'
Where sDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-08-09'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple

```
... WHERE sDate => '2011-01-01'
```

would do, assuming you never have 'future' dates in that table.

Comment: what code do you suggest that I should  use if I have future dates?

Comment: @cha: rionmonster's answer would be the one to use, then.

Comment: you mean this code? DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()), 0)...When I used this, an error statement appears..it says cannot convert 0 to a date. Can you help me solve it?

Comment: No. Rionmonster's answer above: `Where sDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND GETDATE()`

Answer (score 7):

No hardcoding of dates is needed. `DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()), 0)` will give you the first day of the current year. So:

```
...WHERE sDate BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: When I used this, an error statement appears..it says cannot convert 0 to a date. Can you help me solve it?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the [**GETDATE()**](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/sql-current-date/) function, as shown below:

```
SELECT *
FROM 'mytable'
Where sDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I know this is a basic question. Thanks for answering! :-)

Comment: No problem - Glad it helped you out.